# Reading values from file into 2D vector results in all values being zero

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to read a file of integer values and push each value into a 2D vector. For whatever reason, my resulting vector is full of zeros, rather than the values that I just read out of the file. Why is this and how do I fix it?

```
void populateVector(string file, vector<vector<int>>& v, int rows, int cols){
  ifstream read(file);
  int val;

  if (!read.is_open()) {
    throw runtime_error("Output file is not open.");
  } else {
    //Populate 2D vector with values from file
    while (read >> val) {
      cout << val << endl; //Prints each value being processed. Prints proper value.
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
          vector<int> newCol;
          v.push_back(newCol);
          for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            v.at(i).push_back(val);
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

When I print the vector it is populated solely of zeros, even though the read values that are printed to standard output are what I expect (the values from the file).

Comment: Off-topic:  You should pass `file` as a constant reference, e.g. `const string& file`.

Comment: Suggestion: `push_back` the readings into `newCol`, then `push_back` `newcol` into `v`. Less effort and probably easier to read code.

Comment: One thing I see right off the bat is that I don't know if most compilers will accept this: `vector<vector<int>>& v`. You need a space between the second-to-last `>` and the last, as in: `vector<vector<int> >& v`. The reason for this is that the compiler will otherwise get confused, thinking `>>` is an operator.

Comment: Your not considering the first reading of `val` in the `while` conditional expression.  You should read `columns - 1`, because you read the first `val`.

Comment: Looking at the code a bit more, how do you know you are onto a different row? You read one value then do all this stuff with for loops using the same value. This seems kind of odd.

Comment: What is the separator for rows?  Is the number of columns fixed?  Is the number of columns specified in the file?

Comment: @jwir3 that bit of messiness was resolved in C++11. If asker's compiler is getting past that without errors and warnings galore then I'm assuming they have C++11 support.

Comment: @user4581301 Ah, ok. I did not know that. I guess I have to update my gcc. :)

Comment: It appears that your original code is only reading the _first_ value it encounters into the vector, which I anticipate is `0` in your input file. If, for example, I use a file containing `12 13 14`, it outputs a vector of the expected size, but with values of `12` instead of `0`. This might be a clue if you're working on an assignment and want to work through it yourself, rather than just receiving the answer.

Comment: Doesn't both `rows` and `cols` loops run for each `val` read?  Don't you want to read a `val` for each `i`,`j` pair?  I'm guessing that you are making a 2D array of one value.

Comment: @jwir3 Maybe not. You might just need to add -std=c++1x or -std=c++11 to the commandline

Comment: @jwir3 this is very interesting. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution would push all the numbers 'cols' times into each row, that is you end up with row * (cols * n) matrix. Look at your loops correctly.

I assume you meant to read each number only once. Then change your loop to something like following (add error checking as necessary)

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  {
     std::vector<int> newRow;
     for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
     {
        int val;
        read >> val;
        newRow.push_back(val);
     }
     v.push_back(newRow);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read one value at a time, you may want to consider a loop like this:

```
unsigned int column = 0;
std::vector<std::vector<int> > matrix;
std::vector<int> data_row;
while (read >> value)
{
  data_row.push_back(value);
  ++column;
  if (column > MAXIMUM_COLUMNS)
  {
    matrix.push_back(row_data);
    data_row.clear();
    column = 0;
  }
}
```

The above code builds a row of data, one column at a time.  When enough columns are read, the row is then appended to the matrix.

Comment: `MAXIMUM_COLUMNS` can most likely be the `cols` parameter

Comment: How is this different than the method I have written?

Comment: @McFizz Note the lack of inner for loops. Instead there is an if statement determining whether or not the the column being accumulated should be pushed back into the outer "row" `vector`.